# CSS - 1. Header does not scale 2. Floated text is not on the same baseline

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

At [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkkU8/3), you can see a header-bar with a title on the left and some text on the right. The problem should be obvious,

1. the header-bar does not scale with the full site, only with the visible part
2. The right-floated text sticks to the top of the header and is  not on the same baseline as the title.

How can I fix this? Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

*Clarification*: With "the header does not scale" I mean that it does not have a width of 750px as defined in `#header` because the page is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- No need for a float-clearing element. Just add `overflow: auto;` to the container.
- Use `max-width` instead of `width`, as it scales nicely.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/PkkU8/7/

Comment: See my clarification above, sorry. :) What does that `overflow: auto;` change? I don't see a difference (FF), the text still sticks to the top of the bar..

Comment: The `overflow-auto` lets you delete that extra HTML element. If I'm understanding you correctly, does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/PkkU8/9/

Answer (score 1):

For 1) As Blender has mentioned, setting `max-width: 750px` should give you the flexible header width that you are looking for. This way, your header will never be larger than 750px, but can shrink if the window gets smaller than that size.

For 2) If you aren't adverse to it, you can absolutely position the right block instead of floating it. You'd be less prone to issues that float may cause, especially when you can guarantee the right block is going to be smaller than the header itself:

```
.fr {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This also requires that its parent div be positioned either absolutely or relatively to work properly:

```
#head {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: See my clarification above, sorry. 2.) `absolute` makes the text appear at the bottom of the page, and relative does not move it to the right? http://jsfiddle.net/PkkU8/8/

Comment: I have updated my answer for you. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

add padding to class `fr`

```
.fr {
float: right;
padding: 9px 60px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Was `9px` a guess? I don't think this is very flexible, or is it the only option?

Comment: That is to fix top alignment, I don't think there are other option.